# Is there any way I can draw arrows between certain cells of my table?

Tags: longtable, tikz-arrows

I wonder if there is any way I can put arrows in the table like  in the picture below?[image]

The LaTeX code that I use is the following:

```
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{$p$}    &    $=$    &   \textbf{$a$}    & \textbf{$+$}  & \textbf{$b$}  \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{5}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{$p$}    &       &   \textbf{$a$}    & $+$   & \textbf{$b$}  \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
                    & $=$           & $0$       &           & $p$   \\
                    & $=$           & $1$       &           & $p-1$ \\
                    & $=$           & $2$       &           & $p-2$ \\
    \textbf{$p$}    & $\vdots$      & \vdots    & \vdots    & \vdots\\
                    & $=$           & $p-2$     &           & $2$   \\
                    & $=$           & $p-1$     &           & $1$   \\
                    & $=$           & $p$       &           & $0$   \\
\end{longtable}
```

which gives me the following output:

[image]

I hope someone can help me with this one.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  What if the connected  cells appear on different pages?

Comment: I need it to be exactly like the first picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple code with `pstricks`: I add a column of (empty) nodes and connect these nodes with `\ncbar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{postscript}
\psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, linearc=0.05}
\newcommand{\mynode}[1]{\pnode[0pt,0.5ex]{#1}}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|@{\qquad}c@{\qquad}c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{$p$} & $=$ & \textbf{$a$} & \textbf{$+$} & \textbf{$b$} & \qquad\\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{5}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{$p$} & & \textbf{$a$} & $+$ & \textbf{$b$} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
                    & $=$ & $0$ & & $p$ & \mynode{p} \\
                    & $=$ & $1$ & & $p-1$ & \mynode{p1} \\
                    & $=$ & $2$ & & $p-2$ & \mynode{p2} \\
    \textbf{$p$} & $\vdots$ & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \\
                    & $=$ & $p-2$ & & $2$ & \mynode{2} \\
                    & $=$ & $p-1$ & & $1$ & \mynode{1} \\
                    & $=$ & $p$ & & $0$ & \mynode{0} \\
\end{longtable}
\ncbar[arm=1.2cm]{p}{0}
\ncbar[arm=1.6cm]{p1}{1}
\ncbar[arm=2.2cm]{p2}{2}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Similar to @marmot's but I clean these noisy cross-overs and use a virtual column for horizontally aligning the beginnings and ends of arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
\ifmmode%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt]\node(#1){$#2$};
\else
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt]\node(#1){#2};%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{1.8cm}|c|>{\centering}p{1.8cm}|c|>{\centering}p{1.8cm}|@{}p{0pt}@{}} % 
    \hline
    \textbf{$p$}    &    $=$    &\textbf{$a$} & \textbf{$+$} & \textbf{$b$} & \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \textbf{$p$}    &           &\textbf{$a$} & $+$     & \textbf{$b$}  & \tabularnewline
    \hline
                    & $=$       & $0$       &           & $p$      &\tikznode{p2}{} \tabularnewline
                    & $=$       & $1$       &           & $p-1$    &\tikznode{p1}{} \tabularnewline
                    & $=$       & $2$       &           & $p-2$    &\tikznode{p0}{} \tabularnewline
    \textbf{$p$}    & $\vdots$  & $\vdots$  & $\vdots$  & $\vdots$ &\tabularnewline
                    & $=$       & $p-2$     &           & $2$      &\tikznode{0}{}  \tabularnewline
                    & $=$       & $p-1$     &           & $1$      &\tikznode{1}{}  \tabularnewline
                    & $=$       & $p$       &           & $0$      &\tikznode{2}{}  \tabularnewline
  \hline                    
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,line width=.7pt,rounded corners]
 \foreach \X in {0,1,2}
  \draw[-latex] ($(p\X)+(-.7,3pt)$) -- ++({1.2+0.5*\X},0) |- ($(\X)+(-.7,3pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Rather straightforward with Ti*k*Z as long as the table is on one page only.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
\ifmmode%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
\else
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{$p$}    &    $=$    &   \textbf{$a$}    & \textbf{$+$}  & \textbf{$b$}  \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{5}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{$p$}    &       &   \textbf{$a$}    & $+$   & \textbf{$b$}  \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
                    & $=$           & $0$       &           & \tikznode{p0}{$p$}   \\
                    & $=$           & $1$       &           & \tikznode{p1}{$p-1$} \\
                    & $=$           & $2$       &           & \tikznode{p2}{$p-2$} \\
    \textbf{$p$}    & $\vdots$      & \vdots    & \vdots    & \vdots\\
                    & $=$           & $p-2$     &           & \tikznode{2}{$2$}   \\
                    & $=$           & $p-1$     &           & \tikznode{1}{$1$}   \\
                    & $=$           & $p$       &           & \tikznode{0}{$0$}   \\
\end{longtable}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \foreach \X in {0,1,2}
 { \draw[-latex] (p\X) -- ++({1.5+0.5*\X},0) |- (\X);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a version which is closer to your upper picture and also does not use longtable as this is not necessary here.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
\ifmmode%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
\else
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{1.8cm}|c|>{\centering}p{1.8cm}|c|>{\centering}p{1.8cm}|} % 
    \hline
    \textbf{$p$}    &    $=$    &   \textbf{$a$}    & \textbf{$+$}  & \textbf{$b$}  \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \textbf{$p$}    &       &   \textbf{$a$}    & $+$   & \textbf{$b$}  \tabularnewline
    \hline
                    & $=$           & $0$       &           & \tikznode{p0}{$p$}   \tabularnewline
                    & $=$           & $1$       &           & \tikznode{p1}{$p-1$} \tabularnewline
                    & $=$           & $2$       &           & \tikznode{p2}{$p-2$} \tabularnewline
    \textbf{$p$}    & $\vdots$      & $\vdots$    & $\vdots$    & $\vdots$ \tabularnewline
                    & $=$           & $p-2$     &           & \tikznode{2}{$2$}   \tabularnewline
                    & $=$           & $p-1$     &           & \tikznode{1}{$1$}   \tabularnewline
                    & $=$           & $p$       &           & \tikznode{0}{$0$}   \tabularnewline
  \hline                    
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \foreach \X in {0,1,2}
 { \draw[-latex] (p\X) -- ++({1.8+0.5*\X},0) |- (\X);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'm still learning using tikz. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: To make the output look more like the figure in the OP you could give the `\tikznode`s a minimum width...

Comment: @gebruiker I would not redefine `\tikznode` for that but just make the column wider.

Comment: @AmirulAizad If that answer works for you, could you perhaps consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark left of it?

Comment: But then the arrows would still be touching the node text. I added `minimum width=12ex` to the nodes and changed the 1.5 to 2.5 in the `\draw` command. This looks more like the OP. The OP can now still make his columns wider if he wants.

Comment: @gebruiker And what if the OP wants to use `\tikznode` at other places with narrower columns? Of course, if the columns are wider, the distance `1.5` in the overlay tikz pic should be increased.

Comment: A valid point. However creating that space between the node text and the arrow by using a minimum node width very easily creates the desired result. Perhaps define `\newlength{\tikznodewidth}` and set `minimum width=\tikznodewidth` in the definitions. If the OP wants to use `\tikznode` again in other places, he need only set `\setlength{\tikznodewidth}{<desired length>}`.

Comment: @gebruiker I appreciate your comments but I added a second MWE which provides a solution that IMHO is somewhat cleaner.